# How to use multiple useSWR hooks in NextJS with Suspense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-suspense

I have a NextJS project where I'm trying to use SWR to fetch data. My problem is:

when I use more than two `useSWR`-hooks in one component I get these hook errors:

- `Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by ComponentExample. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed.`
- `Uncaught Error: Update hook called on initial render. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.`

Here is a minimum reproduction code repository: https://github.com/LarsFlieger/swr-suspense-multiple

In `Component.tsx` I'm trying to do 3 fetches and console logging the output:

```js
"use client";

import useSWR from "swr";

const fetchWithDelay = async (url: string) => {
    const delay = parseInt(url) * 1000;
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(url), delay));
    return url;
};

export const ComponentExample: React.FC = () => {
    const { data: dataAfter1 } = useSWR("1", fetchWithDelay, {
        suspense: true,
    });
    console.log(dataAfter1);

    const { data: dataAfter2 } = useSWR("2", fetchWithDelay, {
        suspense: true,
    });
    console.log(dataAfter2);

    const { data: dataAfter3 } = useSWR("3", fetchWithDelay, {
        suspense: true,
    });
    console.log(dataAfter3);

    return (
        <main>
            <p>Page loaded!</p>
        </main>
    );
};
```

How can I fix this issue? I can not find any general rule if it's okay to use multiple hooks but as far as I understand it should be okay since:

- in several examples there multiple: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching#dependent

Comment: I created an issue in `vercel/swr`-repo as well: https://github.com/vercel/swr/issues/2849

Comment: Based on the code you provided, It seems you're not using Suspense in proper way. 
Did you wrap your component or page with <Suspense><Suspense/> ?
If you enable suspense option in useSWR, they internally throw Promise, and it seems there's no wrapper that cataches thrown promises.

Comment: @Junghyeonuk Thanks for your comment. I think that the `loading.tsx` from nextjs ( https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming ) uses `Suspense` by default. 

Also I rechecked if you wrap it into a "custom" suspense same problems occurs.

Comment: "*as far as I understand the idea of <Suspense> is to do them parallel by default*" - I doubt that is possible. Afaik, to suspend a component a hook throws an exception, which means that the latter hooks cannot be executed while the first is still fetching. This is a design limitation of React. See e.g. https://github.com/vercel/swr/issues/1711 and https://github.com/vercel/swr/pull/168 for a possible workaround